# Disconnect and reconnect dongle in Linux

Tags: python, linux

Do any one know how to disconnet and reconnect dongle in linux through command line (will be great if told using Ppython too).
Tried to use mount, unmount command but error occurs as

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
```

tried using `udisks` but not even useful to that extend.

**Note:** not just want to disonnect and connect internet connection using(nmcli or like) rather want to eject and reconnect dongle instead.

Comment: This question isn't really suitable for SO (but _might_ be suitable for another Stack Exchange site). but what kind of dongle is it? Eg, is it a USB internet connection dongle?

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://www.greplinux.net/2012/07/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html) mate. I hope you will get your answer from here.

Comment: @PM 2ring its USB internet dongle.

Comment: @Skynet  even this does not work. no such file exist "/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:0017: No such file or directory"

Comment: oh i thought it may work out, well then keep looking you will find solution for sure @Angels